# How do I create a new instance of this slideshow on WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, slideshow

I've attempted to copy and paste this snippet and change the IDs, but it's breaking my theme for some reason. I more than appreciate if anyone can over some helpful suggestions! THanks!

/*** Slideshow ***/

```
$prefix = 'sgt_';

$meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'slide',
    'title' => 'Slideshow Options',
    'page' => 'post',
    'context' => 'side',
    'priority' => 'low',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Show in slideshow',
            'id' => $prefix . 'slide',
            'type' => 'checkbox'
        )
    )
);
add_action('admin_menu', 'sight_add_box');


// Add meta box
function sight_add_box() {
    global $meta_box;

    add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'sight_show_box', $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
}


// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function sight_show_box() {
    global $meta_box, $post;

    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="sight_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';

    echo '<table class="form-table">';

    foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        // get current post meta data
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

        echo '<tr>',
                '<th style="width:50%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
                '<td>';
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
        echo     '<td>',
            '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}

add_action('save_post', 'sight_save_data');

// Save data from meta box
function sight_save_data($post_id) {
    global $meta_box;

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['sight_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code to create new slide post type..

```
    function slider(){
    $labels = array( 'name' => 'Slider', 'singular_name' => 'Slider', 'add_new' => 'Add New', 'add_new_item' => 'Add New Slider', 'edit_item' => 'Edit Slider', 'new_item' => 'New Slider', 'all_items' => 'All Sliders', 'view_item' => 'View Slider', 'search_items' => 'Search Sliders', 'not_found' =>  'No Sliders found', 'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Sliders found in Trash', 'parent_item_colon' => '', 'menu_name' => 'Sliders' );

    $args = array( 'labels' => $labels, 'public' => true, 'publicly_queryable' => true, 'show_ui' => true,  'show_in_menu' => true, 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'slider' ), 'capability_type' => 'post', 'has_archive' => true, 'hierarchical' => false,'menu_position' => null,'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ) ); 
    register_post_type( 'slider', $args );

    $labels = array( 'name' => 'News', 'singular_name' => 'News', 'add_new' => 'Add New', 'add_new_item' => 'Add New News', 'edit_item' => 'Edit News', 'new_item' => 'New News', 'all_items' => 'All Newss', 'view_item' => 'View News', 'search_items' => 'Search Newss', 'not_found' =>  'No Newss found', 'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Newss found in Trash', 'parent_item_colon' => '', 'menu_name' => 'Newss' );

    $args = array( 'labels' => $labels, 'public' => true, 'publicly_queryable' => true, 'show_ui' => true,  'show_in_menu' => true, 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'news' ), 'capability_type' => 'post', 'has_archive' => true, 'hierarchical' => false,'menu_position' => null ); 
    register_post_type( 'news', $args );
    }
add_action('init','slider');
```

Comment: Sorry it's taken so long to get back to you. Thank you so much for your helpful response!